# Reuse id during a jQuery function

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to do not repeat my `#status-message-not-saved` in this code ?

```
$('#form-data :input').change(function() {
    if($('#status-message-not-saved').hasClass('hide') ) {
        $('#status-message-not-saved').removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Assign it to a variable...

Comment: Yes but I can't use `this` at this time ?

Comment: No because the function isn't being invoked on the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just add a class selector.

```
$('#status-message-not-saved.hide').removeClass('hide');
```

However, you don't even need to use the `hasClass` or a class selector here. jQuery `removeClass` doesn't complain when the element doesn't have the class name.

If you want to reuse the jQuery wrapped element, you can cache it.

```
$('#form-data :input').change(function() {
    var $el = $('#status-message-not-saved').removeClass('hide');
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a variable.

```
$('#form-data :input').change(function() {
    var $foo = $('#status-message-not-saved');
    if($foo.hasClass('hide') ) {
        $foo.removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```